# Using OrientDB 2.0.2, a LUCENE query does not seem to respect the "LIMIT n" operator

Tags: lucene, orientdb

Using LUCENE inside of OrientDB seems to work fine, but there are very many LUCENE-specific query parameters that I would ordinarily pass directly to LUCENE (normally through Solr). The first one I need to pass is the result limiter such as `SELECT * FROM V WHERE field LUCENE "Value" LIMIT 10`.

If I use a value that only returns a few rows, I get the performance I expect, but if it has a lot of values, I need the limiter to get the result to return quickly. Otherwise I get an message in the console stating that `The query would return more than 50000 records. Please consider using an index.`

How do I pass additional LUCENE query paramters?

Answer (score 0):

There's a known issue with the query parser which is in the process of being fixed, until then the following workaround should help:

```
SELECT FROM (
    SELECT * FROM V WHERE Field LUCENE 'Value'
) LIMIT 10
```

Alternatively, depending on which client libraries you're using you may be able to set a limit using the out-of-band query settings.

Comment: I'm using the OrientDB Web Studio to issue direct SQL queries. Unfortunately, this proposed solution does not perform any better than previous attempts as the inner query still returns > 50000 rows from the inner query, which produces that same problem.

Comment: Does anyone know when the bug in the query parser is supposed to be fixed? Thanks in advance!